Component on DOM not updating after pinia store is updated
I'm having a problem with pinia store not hot reloading when changes are made unless I restart the vite server or the refresh the browser manually before the updated items will appear
//ExpenseStore.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export const useExpenseStore = defineStore('expense', () => {
  const id = ref(1)
  const transactions = ref([
    { id: id.value++, description: 'Salary', amount: 1000 },
    { id: id.value++, description: 'Rent', amount: -200 },
    { id: id.value++, description: 'Car Payment', amount: -300 }
  ])

  return {
    id,
    transactions
  }
})

main.js
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.use(createPinia())
app.mount('#app')

<template>
  <div v-for="transaction in expenseStore.transactions" :key="transaction.id">
    {{ transaction.id }} : {{ transaction.description }} : ${{ transaction.amount }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useExpenseStore } from '@/stores/ExpenseStore'

const expenseStore = useExpenseStore()
</script>

I've tried some of the solutions I saw on some similar questions but they didn't prove to work.
<script setup>
import {useExpenseStore} from '@/stores/ExpenseStore'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

//First one I saw
const expenseStore = useExpenseStore()
import { computed } from 'vue'
const { transactions } = storeToRefs(expenseStore)

//Another one
const expenseStore = useExpenseStore()

const transactions = computed(() => expenseStore.transactions)

<script>

I've also done
import { defineStore, acceptHMRUpdate } from 'pinia'

export const useExpenseStore = defineStore('expense',() => {
  // options...
})


if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useExpenseStore, import.meta.hot))
}

None of them worked
I've even changed the whole project setup, created a new one, also changed environment from vscode to google IDX but still no solution.
There's no error whatsoever in the console too
But an older project which I'm worked on about two months ago still works, so I tried to install the same versions of vue,vite and pinia as the old project but still to no avail

Which changes exactly  do not work? What are these "updated items"? This looks hacky, id: id.value++, it's unknown if it's the part of the problem. Since the problem may be specific to a particular vite setup, please, provide a way to reproduce.

@Estus Flask When the app is mounted everything works just that when you add another transaction to the transactions array and save it, it doesn't get updated on the DOM until you refresh the browser or restart the vite server

The question needs a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What you listed is regular pinia setup with no problems expected. You didn't show how the transactions are added. Do you mean you add new entries in an editor or push them to "transactions" programmatically?

@Estus Flask Thanks a lot I've figured it out. it was a misconfiguration in the main.js file
